# Obtener la fecha actual en caso que nos se coloque alguna

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Estoy haciendo un pequeño formulario, y quiero que si no se coloca la fecha, automáticamente ponga la fecha actual:

La fecha la estoy solicitando en rabel:

```
        <label for="fecha">Fecha:
            <input type="date" name="fecha">
        </label>
```

y este el php que intente:

```
            if(empty($_POST["fecha"])){
                $hoy = getdate();
                $fecha = $hoy['mday']. "-".$hoy['mon']."-" .$hoy['year'] ;
            }else{
                $fecha=$_POST['fecha'];}
```

¿Cómo podría hacer esto?

De antemano muchas gracias!

Comment: codigo para obtener fecha $fecha = date('Y-m-d');

Comment: Funciona, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

El siguiente ejemplo debería funcionarte sin problemas. Con el operador ternario para hacerlo mas simple.

```
$fecha = (empty($_POST['fecha'])) ? date('d-m-Y') : $_POST['fecha'];
```

De todos modos el si la fecha la vas a almacenar en una base de datos, el formato debería ser date('Y-m-d').
Tambien podrias hacerlo mas simple con el operador de fusión nula.

```
$fecha = ($_POST['fecha']) ?? : date('d-m-Y')
```

Lo que hace este último es devolver el primero operando, $_POST['fecha'], si es true. Si es false, devuelve date('d-m-Y').

Comment: Si, guardare el valor en una base de datos y utilizando la segunda opción sale el siguiente error:
`syntax error, unexpected token ":" `

Comment: Hola José. Es verdad,  fue un error mío en el código que le pase  en ese caso no van los dos puntos. Quedaría así. $fecha = ($_POST['fecha']) ??  date('d-m-Y) . Este operador funciona desde php7+